# XAML/C# - Events Assignment

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, events

```
<Button Content="{Binding telefone}"  
Click="{Binding telefone, Converter={StaticResource ButtonClick}}" />
```

Hi!

How do I associate the click event to a button through a 'converter'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight parser is unable to event handlers to bindings. Instead, use the Command attribute.

```
<Button Command="{Binding telefone}" />
```

C#:

```
public class Telephone: ICommand
{

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Telephone clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought so. You can not use 'converters'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make your converter return the name of the callback as string.

(That's how I do that)

Comment: really? how do i get a callback method as string?

Comment: let's say you have a method called "onButtonClick" in your code, simply return it as string from your converter.

Comment: return "onButtonClick"; and make sure you have that method in your form.